# searchAndGetScreenPopUrl: Field name translations

Tags: opencti, softphone

The method searchAndGetScreenPopUrl returns a response of matching objects, together with the attributes selected in the softphone config. However the response only contains the internal names, not their translations. Is there any way to consume these translations (without creating an extra apex class that would cause yet another request)? Its a bit unfortunate that the user selects the translated fields within the softphone settings, then receives the internal names in the cti adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Digging further into the documentation I found that getSoftPhoneLayout actually returns both, the internal name plus the display name of configured attributes.

This way it is only a matter of mapping between the two of them.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_getsoftphonelayout.htm